# Web Scraping links

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, if-statement, web-scraping

I am working on scraping links from a Christmas tree farm website. First, I used this tutorial [method](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vv_FX3FSvGo) to get all the links. Then, I noticed that the links that I wanted did not lead with the proper hypertext transfer protocol, so I created a variable to concatenate. Now I am trying to create a `if` statement that grabs each link and looks for any two characters followed by "xmastrees.php". If that is true then my concatenate variable to the front of it. If the link does not contain the specific text then it is deleted. For example `NYxmastrees.php` will be `http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/NYxmastrees.php` and `../disclaimer.htm` will be removed. I've tried multiple ways, but can't seem to find the right one.

Here is what I currently have and keep running into a syntax error: del. I commented out that line and get another error saying my string object has no attribute 're'. This confuses me because I though i could use regex with strings??

```
source = requests.get('http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
concatenate = 'http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/'

find_state_group = soup.find('div', class_ = 'alert')
for link in find_state_group.find_all('a', href=True):
    if link['href'].re.search('^.\B.\$xmastrees'):
        states = concatenate + link
    else del link['href']
    print(link['href']
```

Error with `else del link['href']`:

```
    else del link['href']
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Error without `else del link['href']`:

```
    if link['href'].re.search('^.\B.\$xmastrees'):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 're'
```

Comment: `else:` on the next line ->  `del link['href']` and `re.search('^.\B.\$xmastrees',  link['href'])`

Comment: @ Pedro Lobito return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'

Comment: Is [this](https://pastebin.com/HSFFGw6P) that you need? If so, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

u = "http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/"
soup = bs(requests.get(u).text, 'html5lib')

find_state_group = soup.find('div', {"class": 'alert'})
for link in find_state_group.find_all('a', href=True):
    if "mastrees" in link['href']:
        states = u + link['href']
        print(states)
```

---

```
http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/ALxmastrees.php
http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/AZxmastrees.php
http://www.pickyourownchristmastree.org/AKxmastrees.php
...
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/@lobopt/61419586web-scraping-links)

Comment: Yes, this works. Could you please explain why mine was not working after I made those changes you first commented?

Comment: you add a couple of syntax errors on the regex and elif part.

Comment: Right, so I made those corrections on my end and ended up getting the error I posted as the second comment. Were there more errors than just those two? Also, what if the text I am looking for needed to very specific. In such a way that I need to use those special characters (^\B\$)?

Comment: You can create a new question, for example, I need a regex to match a URL containing `ZZZ`, I've tried `ABC` but got error `XYZ`. Please post the new question link here so I can help you.